# How to sequence stored procedure process on Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a stored procedure that has a `DateTime` parameter, and I want to execute the pipeline sequence, so it will start first on 'JAN-FEB' and then 'MAR-APR' then 'MEI-JUN'

How can I do that ? without using hard pipeline from the stored procedure?

So for the example like this:

[image]

I have 3 stored procedures with different `DateTime`. And I don't want it run like this.

[image]

What can I do to solve my problem ? What function from Azure Data Factory can I use for this case?

Note:

- Why I want to sequence this stored procedure is to prevent crash from `Azure Synapse`. Because in this script will process around **1 billion** rows from the source table, and I need to batch this process to prevent from any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you can define an array type variable in ADF. Eg.  `['JAN-FEB','MAR-APR','MEI-JUN']`
   [image]
2. Traverse this array via Foreach activity. Select `Sequential`, this will **sequentially** cycle the internal activities. Add dynamic content, select your declared variable name.
   [image]
3. Inside Foreach activity, we can use a stored procedure, click `Import` will import params in your stored procedure. Then add dynamic content `@item()`.
   [image]

ADF will execute the stored procedure sequentially.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, but here I want to ask, Is it possible to add more than 1 variable on `ForEach` items ? If it possible, how about the dynamic content written on this `ForEach` and `Value` on Stored Procedure, in your explanation parameter only refer to the `@item()` which is only contain `ParamArray` value?

Comment: Only one parameter of array type can be received at a time in Foreach activity. ` @item()` represents each element in the `ParamArray` array.

Comment: Can I use `Set Variable` function to add more parameter for this `ForEach` ? Or maybe, Can I set variable on base, and call it on `Stored Procedure` parameter value ?

Comment: Yes, we can use `Set variable` activity inside `ForEach` activity.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, can I set variable on environment, and call it on `Stored Procedure` parameter value ?

Comment: I thought that you have 3 stored procedures to be executed sequentially, and the values of the parameters they receive are the same each time.

Comment: Hahaha, I'm sorry, suddenly I got another insight from your answer. Okay thank you so much Joseph ! very appreciate for your answer